# Limited dataset using Script rather than IMPORTDATA

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following script to work around an IMPORTDATA issue I am experiencing.

```
function Script() {
  var url = 'file.csv';
  var csv = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var data = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet 1').getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

This CSV file currently contains 26000 entries (and growing), however the number of results displayed through this script is 2500.

Potentially a noob question, but not sure why... If someone can help, that would be great.

Comment: How does 'file.csv' function as a url?  Generally I'd assume that there's something wrong with the data.  Look at it carefully with an ascii editor.  How large is the csv file? in bytes

Comment: It is a redash report. The URL (I've changed the URL as it contains sensitive information) is displayed as: https://redash.mid.tools/api/queries/x/results.csv?api_key=examplekey

Comment: Okay I just wanted to be sure.  Often we get questions from folks that don't have a clue. What's the file size?

Comment: It's 1958KB file size

Comment: I guess at this point I'd take a close look at the content in an ascii editor and make sure that there are not any anomalies that would cause the parseCsv to end early.  And make sure that the file you're getting out of the fetch is correct.  You could pour it into a textarea and them put it into an editor